# Creating Multiple Values In For Loop [AS3]

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop

I am trying to create multiple Numbers with for loop.

```
var sasutu1x : Number = Number(sasutu1.text);
var sasutu2x : Number = Number(sasutu2.text);
var sasutu3x : Number = Number(sasutu3.text);
var sasutu4x : Number = Number(sasutu4.text);
var sasutu5x : Number = Number(sasutu5.text);
var sasutu6x : Number = Number(sasutu6.text);
```

My Solution :

```
var i:int;
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
var this["sasutu" i + "x"] : Number = Number(["sasutu" + i].text);
}
```

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Vector, or if you want to get a reference to that number by name later, you can also use a Dictionary.

```
var i:int;
var sasutuDict:Dictionary = new Dictionary(true);

for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    sasutuDict["sasutu" i + "x"] = Number(["sasutu" + i].text);
}
```

One advantage of a dictionary, is that you can even do something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
     var sasutuTexField:TextField =  this["sasutu" + i];
     sasutuDict[sasutuTexField] = Number(sasutuTexField.text);
}
```

Meaning you can have the key of the dictionary be the text field itself.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to use a Vector instead.

```
var vec:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>();
for (var i:int = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    vec.push(Number(["sasutu"+i].text));
}
```